# Extract tokens from log files in unix

Tags: shell, unix, sed, grep

I have a directory containing log files.

We are interested in a particular log line which goes like `'xxxxxxxxx|platform=SUN|.......|orderId=ABCDEG|........'`
We have to extract all similar lines from the log files in this directory,and print out the token 'ABCDEG'.

Duplication is acceptable.
How do we achieve this with a single unix command operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -r '/platform=.*orderId=/s/.*orderId=([^|]+).*/\1/g' *
```

From all lines containing `platform=` && `orderId=` (`/platform=.*orderId=/`), take the `non-|` sequence of characters (`([^|]+)`)after `orderId=`.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F'|' '$2=="platform=SUN"{sub(/orderId=/,"", $4); print $4}' logFile*
```

**output**

ABCDEG

IHTH

Comment: Thi presupposes that these matches are in fixed columns.

Comment: Answer is based on the evidence provided and has a money back guarantee ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -rP "\|platform=SUN\|.*(?<=\|orderId=)" | sed s/.*platform=SUN.*orderId=// | sed s/\|.*//
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ str='xxxxxxxxx|platform=SUN|.......|orderId=ABCDEG|........'
$ grep -Po 'platform=SUN.*orderId=\K[^|]*' <<< "$str"
ABCDEG
```

This requires Perl compatible regular expressions (`-P`); `-o` retains just the match. `\K` is variable length look-behind: "match the stuff to the left of it, but don't include it in the matched string".

Answer (score 0):

From the logs directory you could run the following command:

```
sed -n /platform=SUN/p   *  | sed 's#.*orderId=\(.*\)|.*$#\1#'
```